# In reveal.js slides, how can I make list items begin semi faded, then highlight sequentially?

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I'm making a slide that contains several list items, which I will discuss in order.
I'd like my slide to begin by having all of the items visible but partially faded out.
As I work through them, I'd like to be able to use data fragments to un-fade the point that I'm discussing, so that it is highlighted.

I can do basically the opposite using:

```html
<section>
    <h3>my title/h3>
    <ul>
        <li class="fragment semi-fade-out" data-fragment-index="1">
            Point 1
        </li>
        <li class="fragment semi-fade-out" data-fragment-index="2">
            Point 2
        </li>
        <li class="fragment semi-fade-out" data-fragment-index="3">
            Point 3
        </li>
        <li class="fragment semi-fade-out" data-fragment-index="4">
            Point 4
        </li>
        <li class="fragment semi-fade-out" data-fragment-index="5">
            Point 5
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I'd basically like to have a `semi-fade-in-then-semi-fade-out` type of fragment, but I'm not sure how to make this happen.

I have tried using nested `<li>` elements, which didn't work, and I've also tried nesting `<p>` elements inside of the `<li>` elements each with their own data fragment class sort of like is show in the reveal.js documentation https://revealjs.com/fragments/#nested-fragments.

Is there a good way to make this happen?